# Php Acting Different On Different Server

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am having an issue with code not working on a server but working within my local environment using Xampp. The Issues I am having are:

- First Prepared Statement Only Gets Implemented
- usersId is not returned (couldn't get last_insert_id() to work)

I was using PHP on xampp but thought this was due to the server being PHP5 and there being version issues but I updated my Xampp to PHP5 and this problem still occurs.

```
    mysqli_autocommit($conn,FALSE);
    $insertUser = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES (?,?)";
    $userStatement = $conn->prepare($insertUser);
    $userStatement->bind_param("ss", $u, $p);   
    $u = $username;
    $p = $encryptedPassword;    
    $userStatement->execute();
    $userStatement->close();

    $id = "";
    $query = "SELECT userid from users WHERE username = '$username'";
    $resultID = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die($query."<br/>   <br/>".mysql_error());
    if($resultID == false){
    echo "ERROR1";
    }
    else {
        foreach($resultID as $row){
        $userid = $row['userid'];
        }   
    }   
    $buildbirthday = "{$day}/{$month}/{$year}";

    $insertDetails = "INSERT INTO userdetails(userid, firstname, lastname,   birthdate, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $detailsStatement = $conn->prepare($insertDetails);
    $detailsStatement->bind_param("issss", $i, $f, $n, $b, $e);
    $i = $userid;
    $f = $firstname;
    $n = $secondname;
    $b = $buildbirthday;
    $e = $email;
    $detailsStatement->execute();
    $detailsStatement->close();
```

Comment: `mysqli_query` but `mysql_error`, really?

Comment: Do you have something in the server's logs or an error message ?

Comment: @u_mulder I've changed it and there is no error.

Comment: @Letsrocks I don't have access to the server's logs. There is literally no error message other it just does not display.